# Why is the Y axis pointing upward? I don't want it to

Tags: axis

I am working on a project right now and somehow the axis went all out of whack. When I use the gizmo under global mode, the z axis is the one pointed up. But when I put it under Normal mode, or try "G + Y", the Y axis is going up. Can someone help me get the Z axis back to the up/down position?

[image]

When I apply rotation and scale, it does this when I click "G + Y"
[image]

Here is an image of my viewport navigation gizmo, and I have it set to global orientation, not normal. Still doing the same thing.
[image]

Comment: Maybe what's confusing is the camera orientation - maybe you need to change your view, not your objects... Can you make a screenshot of your [viewport navigation gizmo](https://i.imgur.com/GBbYERl.png)?

Comment: I edited my original post to show the viewport navigation gizmo.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the rotation to make sure that it resets the rotation and again the Z will show up as usual.

To do it, simply press Ctrl+A, and then apply rotation.

Comment: And the reset needs to be done in _Object Mode_, otherwise in _Edit Mode_ the shortcut Ctrl+A is _Skin Resize_. I just mention it because the screenshot shows _Edit Mode_.

Comment: I tried applying rotation in object mode and in edit mode it is still the same. Y is the up and down.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point to orientations, like global or normal, is to give you useful axes to move things-- *different* axes.  If you want Z to mean globally up, use global orientation.

Normal orientation is an orientation where +Z points in the direction that the normal points-- generally speaking, the direction that a face is facing (but it depends also on selection mode and pivot point.)  Using normal orientation is useful precisely because this +Z is a different direction than the world +Z.